# Basic color reduction algorithm in OpenCV

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, opencv, colors

Here is the formula for basic color reduction in OpenCV that I read in a book.

```
//p is the value of the channel of a pixel
//n is the reduction factor
p = (p/n)*n + n/2; //integer division
```

I understand that the first expression `(p/n)*n` is the first multiple of `n` less than or equal to `p`. I think that just this is enough for color reduction by the factor of `n`. But I don't get what is the need to add `n/2` to it.
And also, if `p=255` and `n=5`, this formula will try to set `p = 257`, won't it overflow the range of p?
Please explain.

Comment: Could you add name the book? (p/n)*n doesn`t make sense at all.

Comment: OpenCV 2 Computer Vision Application Programming Cookbook - Robert Laganiere

Comment: Integer division, OK.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

With `n=255`,  `(((p)/n)*n)` would return 0 for p < 255, and 255 for p == 255.

To be balanced you would want to return 0 for p < 128 and 255 for p >= 128. This can be achieved with:

```
((p + n/2) / n) * n
```

This is a bit like `((p / n) + 0.5) * n`, except that you obviously can't do that. The effect is to give rounding, instead of truncation on the the result of `p/n`. Actually this only works well for some values of n.

An easy way to get exactly what you want would be to use a lookup table.

I agree `((p)/n)*n    + n/2` has problems, as pointed out by old-ufo

Comment: This method is producing very weird result, new colours are forming, the method specified by the book works well, I just can't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

They say that n/2 is needed to have "central" position instead of minimum, but you are right it looks like not needed. 
Lets assume I want to have 2 colors - black and white, so n=255. Without n/2 I would have 0 and 255 as a result. With n/2 - 127 and 382, which seems not correct.

Comment: Yes, can't understand why they put n/2 over there.